# Convert date format from JSON in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting the date format in JSON respose like below

```
14-JAN-14
```

I need to convert it in my ajax success function like below

```
2014-01-14
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Is the year the first 2 digit sequence in the original string, or the last?

Comment: First one is date, dd-MM-yy

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in JS:

```
    var d = new Date('14-Jan-14');
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date);
```

I've added in the add a zero and slice the last two characters so that you have your double digit date month format too.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/c42Y7/) the fiddle.